# How is the instance of Show for String written?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a basic question about definining instances of typeclasses. I am using the Show typeclass as an example, and I am considering only the function show within the class. The Show instance for a concrete type like Bool is simple

```
instance Show Bool where
  show x = {function of x here}
```

but for String it is not:

```
instance Show String where
  show x = {function of x here}
```

produces understandably an error

```
Illegal instance declaration for ‘Formatter String’
  (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
   where T is not a synonym.
   Use TypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for ‘Formatter String’
```

and of course the following is not allowed:

```
instance Show [Char] where
  show x = {function of x here}
```

I could define a newtype

```
newtype String2 = String2 String 
instance Formatter String2 where
  format (String2 x) = {function of x here}
```

which however does not allow me to do show "test", as I am able to do in Haskell.

What essential feature of typeclasses am I missing?

Comment: String formatting is part of the Char instance, via the showList method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Show` typeclass actually has three member functions, `show`, `showsPrec`, and `showList`.  In the instance for `Show Char`, the `showList` function is overloaded to output quote marks and shove all the letters together without delimiters:

From [`GHC.Show`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Show.html#Show):

```
instance  Show Char  where
    showsPrec _ '\'' = showString "'\\''"
    showsPrec _ c    = showChar '\'' . showLitChar c . showChar '\''

    showList cs = showChar '"' . showLitString cs . showChar '"'
```

Where [`showLitString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Show.html#showLitString) is defined as:

```
showLitString :: String -> ShowS
-- | Same as 'showLitChar', but for strings
-- It converts the string to a string using Haskell escape conventions
-- for non-printable characters. Does not add double-quotes around the
-- whole thing; the caller should do that.
-- The main difference from showLitChar (apart from the fact that the
-- argument is a string not a list) is that we must escape double-quotes
showLitString []         s = s
showLitString ('"' : cs) s = showString "\\\"" (showLitString cs s)
showLitString (c   : cs) s = showLitChar c (showLitString cs s)
```

So there is no `Show String` instance, it's simply that `Show Char` defines how to call `show` on `[Char]` values specifically.

Comment: There's another part to the story that explain how `Char`'s implementation of `showList` gets called during `show "hello"`, which is the definition of `show` for `Show a => [a]` which is defined as `show = showList`. The behaviour for non-`Char` instances is actually provided elsewhere in the default definition of `showList` in the class declaration for `Show`.