# Strange "Overlapping instances for [Char]" when an instance is defined for String and List

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

main = do
  print "hello"
  print $ getHello $ "hello"


class Example a where
  getHello :: a -> String

instance Example String where
  getHello _ = "blablabla"

instance Example a => Example [a] where
  getHello v = undefined
```

The above code gives an error of:

> ```
> • Overlapping instances for Example [Char]
>     arising from a use of ‘getHello’
>   Matching instances:
>     instance Example String -- Defined at x.hs:12:10
>     instance Example a => Example [a] -- Defined at x.hs:15:10
> • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘getHello $ "hello"’
>   In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ getHello $ "hello"
>   In the expression:
>     do print "hello"
>        print $ getHello $ "hello"
> ```

I don't understand why though. I understand that `String = [Char]`, but there is no instance defined for `Example Char`, so why would it be overlapping? From my understanding if `instance Example Char` is not defined in the above, then neither will `instance Example [Char]`.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't how it works. When looking for an instance GHC first looks at the "instance head" (which in this case is simply `instance Example [a]`) and matches on that - it only looks at constraints afterwards.

Comment: The duplicate I marked is literally the first result of a search for `[haskell] overlapping instances`... There's a *lot* of high-quality answers on here, you should definitely try to use that resource!

Comment: You can use the [`Show` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951718/how-is-the-instance-of-show-for-string-written) where you define the `Show [a]` instance in terms of `showsPrec = const showList`. `showList` is an extra method of `Show` that defaults to a `[l,i,s,t]`-presentation. The method is overridden in `Show Char` with a `"string"`-presentation

Comment: What would happen if someone came along later and _defined_ `instance Example Char`?